# g++ with -m32 --coverage profile .gcda: Cannot open

Tags: gcc, code-coverage

When I'm trying to compile my C/C++ software using gcc/g++ with -m32 option on RedHat 6.10 which is a 64bit OS, we have a Dell isilon file system exporting 64 bit file ID's we get a run-time error using code coverage compile options.  I wrote a simple main() test app test.cpp and compile with the following compile options.

g++ --coverage -m32 test.cpp -o test

When I run the 32bit executable we get a run-time error relating to our file system exporting 64bit file ID's vs 32 bit.  We don't want to change to a 32bit file ID export.

./test
profiling:test.gcda: Cannot open

If we compile the app without the -m32 option the problem goes away.  However, I need to compile with -m32 for other reasons outside the scope of this discussion.

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC)
RedHat 6.10 64bit OS

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a later version of gcc has fixed this problem.  I now know that gcc version 8.2.0 compiles properly and doesn't have the error about not being able to find the .gcda file.  This makes sense since the Dell isilon system is newer and the gcc compiler version we've been using with RedHat 6.10 is quite old.